# Trying to find server name in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to find server name of sql server using below code :-

```
DataTable dt = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
```

When control goes to above statement the application hangs.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: where is the code? please post your sample code

Comment: i am working on WinForms

Answer (score 0):

use below link for your code link is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources.aspx

Comment: you can use: cmbshowallsqlserver.Items.Add(
    string.Format(@"{0}\{1}",
                  server[table.Columns["ServerName"]],
                  server[table.Columns["InstanceName"]])
);